# Counting and print number of points from a CSV in a series polygons / buffered points in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, printing, point-in-polygon

I'd like to compare the number of calls from gps coordinates to the population around those coordinates in Google Earth Engine. My plan was to count the number of incidents (points from a table: Ola_Orders_13_May_2020) that fall within a series of polygons or buffered points and compare this to the population under the same buffered points and to export the results in a table.

I've summed the population within the buffered points from 'CIESIN/GPWv4/unwpp-adjusted-population-count', and printed as a table. I'd like to compare the number of occurrences (points) from the imported CSV table (Ola_Orders_13_May_2020) with the population in that area and print in a similar table.

My script below (missing the imported table):

```
//Map the Reports
var Incidents = table2.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(50, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(Incidents.draw({color: '000000', strokeWidth: 0}), {opacity: 1}, 'Reports')


var suburbs = ee.FeatureCollection([
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([46.688283, 24.598619]), {name: '23593'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([43.921886, 26.391658]), {name: '19358'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([46.732708, 24.691544]), {name: '15856'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([39.825922, 21.4192]), {name: '10210'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([55.3724, 25.277]), {name: '18934'}),



]).map(function(suburb) { return suburb.buffer(1000); });
print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: ee.ImageCollection('CIESIN/GPWv4/unwpp-adjusted-population-count'),
    regions: suburbs,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    seriesProperty: 'name',
  })
  .setChartType('Table')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Estimated Population by location',
    vAxis: {title: 'Population in 1 Kilometer radius'},
  }));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e8439dbe7722237fb721f8c6cd8b99e

Comment: Bonus questions break the One question per Question policy. One focused question is your goal (and the relevant code should be in the body of the question).

Comment: Thanks @vince edited accordingly.